# The TLD for the class org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag specifies an invalid body-content (JSP) for a SimpleTag

Tags: spring, jsp, tld, apache-tiles

I work with Java WEB-application: maven+spring_mvc+jsp+Apache-Tiles+eclipse+tomcat.

Apllication good startup and work from Eclipse (tomcat plugin, from files),
but when i build war-file and deploy him, i get errors:

```
*org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/layouts/layout.jsp (line: 23, column: 3) The TLD for the class org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag specifies an invalid body-content (JSP) for a SimpleTag.
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:149)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:820)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1795)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)*
```

my layouts.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="/unetProj/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        media="screen">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="/unetProj/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div id="form_container">
        <div id="header">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
        </div>

        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />

        <div id="footer">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

layouts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/pages/layouts/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/pages/layouts/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/pages/layouts/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/pages/layouts/footer.jsp" />
  </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

mvc-dispather-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan> 


     <!-- Tiles Configuration -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/pages/layouts/layouts.xml</beans:value>
                <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/pages/**/views.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

one views.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition extends="base.definition" name="entity/index">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/entity/index.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition extends="base.definition" name="entity/addForm">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/entity/addForm.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition extends="base.definition" name="entity/add">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/entity/add.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: Show us the contents of the file /WEB-INF/pages/layouts/layout.jsp please.

Comment: Show us the content what you are inserting into "body"

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: This is the error I get: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /abc.jsp (line: 384, column: 3) The TLD for the class com.abc.tags.ActionTag specifies an invalid body-content (JSP) for a SimpleTag.